# How to program a python file to use terminal options on mac

Tags: python, command-line, macos-mojave

I am building a python file and instead of asking for user input I want it to get the information on the execution command. For example, I want to be able to type in

```
python code.py -i "information"
```

Instead of having to execute code.py and then tell the code "information". How do I do this? P.S. I am using MacOS mojave as the tags indicate. Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at how to process command line arguments for python

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `sys.argv` in your Python script to read command-line arguments and store them in a list of strings that you can then parse, as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Then, from the terminal:

```
> python code.py -i "foo bar"
['code.py', '-i', 'foo bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `argparse` module to use command line arguments.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html